# TFS 2017 Build agent testing connection failure

Tags: team-foundation-server, build-server

I have a problem connecting the build agent to tfs.

I run the ./config from a powershell with elevated credentials and I proceed to the point where I get the prompt

> ```
> Testing agent connection
> ```

Right after that I get An error occured while sending the request.

The diag logs only have the

> WinHttpException: The operation timed out

I have disabled all firewalls. I have tried token authentication but to no avail.

Any suggestions as to where I should look at for this error?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? Are you able to connect to the required locations through telnet on port 80?

Comment: Are you able to login as the service account user and hit TFS in a browser?

Comment: Yes. The browser connects perfectly well and visual studio too. I can hit port 80 and the agent is getting created, it just can't pass the testing agent connection phase.